# Unable to run azure app service after deploying War file

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

I renamed my war file to ROOT.war and deployed on azure web app service via FTP but it fails to start giving an error of 502. I get " there was insufficient free space available after evicting expired cache entries " from log stream. Anyone know how to solve this?

UPDATE:
@alok I tried deploying with curl it gave me an error of invalid credentials.
I am copying app FTP app credentials from deployment Center

```
    Server Error
    401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
    You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

(AZURE CLI is installed on my system) also when I try to deploy using power shell it says

Publish-AzWebapp : The term 'Publish-AzWebapp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I managed to get my war working on azure from Eclipse:

1. Install **Azure Tool kit for Eclipse** from https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/azure-toolkit-eclipse
   during installation eclipse will restart a couple of times.
2. Right click on **your project** from drop down; hover to Azure and select **Publish as Azure Webapp..**
3. Create a new linux based resource group with required Jre and tomcat version
4. Hit Deploy !

Answer (score 0):

Please try using /WarDeploy:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#deploy-war-file

It will take care of expanding the content of the WAR file in the content folder for your Web App.

If you still run into issues, please file a support ticket and we will find out the root cause since we will need more info.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and looking into my issue
 but now I am getting an error of 
"**could not find -archive path**"
I have attached a screenshot of my issue here: 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CISK3aZIoAI51Yivxq5iJVUhnlGmRfEp/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using curl ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#with-curl
Also seems like you are running powreshell from portal. You can try running locally so that ArchivePath can be resolved. 
Let me know how it goes.